# Delete command not working in laravel using axios

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with delete command. I receive this error in the console

```
 DELETE http://localhost:8000/delete/37 
405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Am using laratrust to set the roles. Update and insert are working well the problem is delete.

in my AdminController

```
  public function destroy($id)
    {
        $testUser = Auth::user();

        if ($testUser->hasRole('superadministrator')) 
        { 
        $user=User::findOrFail($id);
        $user ->delete();
        return ['message'=>'Message Deleted'];
        }
    }
```

Vue Js table

```
<tbody>
         <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
          <td>{{user.id}}</td>
           <td>{{user.name}}</td>
           <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        <td><a href="#" @click="editModal(user)"><i class="fa fa-edit text-         blue"></i></a>
           /
        <a href="#" @click="deleteUser(user.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash text-red"></i></a>

                </td>
                </tr>
                  </tbody>
```

Method

```
 deleteUser(id){
   axios.delete("delete/"+id);
   //console.log('Your form id is'+id);

  },
```

web route

```
Route::post('delete/{id}','AdminController@destroy');
```

When i try to view my routes using php artisan route:list i get this
Php artisan route list

```
trust\Middleware\LaratrustRole:superadministrator      |
|        | POST      | delete/{id}                         |
 | App\Http\Controllers\AdminController@destroy                           | web
                                                       |
|
```

Comment: `Route::post` != `axios.delete` else `Route::delete() === axios.delete`

Comment: @KamleshPaul thanks should i write this in web api?

Comment: Yes `Route::delete('delete/{id}','AdminController@destroy');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your route with delete method. It can remain within `routes/web.php` if it is consumed by the frontend within the same project

```php
Route::delete('delete/{id}','AdminController@destroy');
```